# Deploying a Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, deployment

I created a Winforms app for a friend so that he can quickly look up some info in a database we share. I want to send him a copy of the .exe file, but zipping the file and sending it to him doesn't work. It works on my local machine, but not his. Is there a proper way of deploying or packaging the file so that he can use it from his local machine? I've read some into this, though most of the info is dating from 2009-2010. Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Describe "does not work". Does your friend's PC have the same or higher version of .Net as yours?

Comment: are you sending the manifest file also? **YourApplicationName.exe.config**, also try sending him the zipped bin/debug or bin/release folder to see if it works that way.

Comment: Also, will he have remote access to the database?

Comment: I knew I should have documented the error he received. I figured it wasn't as easy as copying the .exe over to him. He won't know how to set any of this up, so I'm going to have to do more research on how to include all of this stuff and get it to him.